# Firebase and SQL operators

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to ask because I am very confused about something.I can't find it nowhere.
Does Firestore
1)support whole operators of  SQL SELECT?
2)it doesnt support SQL SELECT?
3)or support a small number of operators SQL SELECT?

which one is true?
I ask that question because I see it somewhere and I didn't remember where.
The issue is I know about firebase a lot.I know and for local database.
I know that when we use firebase we use some SQL or we can create it in the website.
I try search theory about this but I didn't find anything similar to this.
What is your aspect of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a platform with 18 or so products, so you'll want to clarify which one you're asking about.

Luckily for the sake of its questions, both of the databases in Firebase (Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database) are NoSQL databases, which (as the name implies) means that they're **not** SQL databases at all.

Neither Firestore nor Realtime Database supports SQL operators, and in fact they don't support many of the operations you may be familiar with from SQL at all. Common SQL operations, such as projections (`SELECT`), server-side joins (`JOIN`), groupings (`GROUP BY`), and aggregation (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc) are all non-existent in the Firebase (and many other) NoSQL databases.

What both of these databases **do** bring (and why you'll typically pick them) is:

- Direct access from client-side application code, with a server-side security rules model to ensure all access is authorized.
- Realtime synchronizes of changes from the database to the client, meaning you don't have to poll the server for updates.
- Massive scalability (Firestore more on the number of concurrent reads, Realtime Database more on the smaller writes).

If those are what drew you to Firebase, I recommend learning more about it by reading the documentation, and/or taking a tutorial/codelab. If you were hoping to find a free cloud-hosted SQL database, Firebase is not that - and you're probably better off looking elsewhere.